# Send Authorization cookie when using socket.io client inside Iframe via WebSocket

Tags: socket.io

I'm trying to create a websocket connection using socket.io client.
My issue starts when my app is running inside an Iframe.
The browser does not send the Authorization cookie which is being **set by the server**.

There is no CORS issue since the iframe and the server are running on the same domain.

The cookie configurations are: HttpOnly = true, Secure = true, SameSite = Strict.

It does work when the app is running without an iframe.

Example of my code

```
    this.socket = io(`/${namespace}`, {
      transports: ['websocket'],
      path: '/.../socket.io'
    });
```

Comment: Try specifying the domain property in your cookie config. If you set it like 'domain.com', then the browser may have to send your cookie to 'domain.com' and all of its subdomains. Beside that, I don't know your project requirements but you are handle the SameSite politics wrong. Try switching it between 'lax' or 'strict' depending of the use.